# Parse output of a for loop into a variable as a comma delimited string

Tags: bash, shell, variables

I'm grabbing all the filenames from a directory and I want to create a comma delimited string of these filenames so that I can pass that string as an argument to an application. This is my code snippet:

```
if [[ -n $(ls | grep lpt) ]]; then
  for files in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    #parse output into variable fileList
  done
fi
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You should probably be using an array instead.

Comment: the application that I need to pass this to accepts file names in a comma delimited string like `$program -file 'file1,file2,file3'`

Comment: What application is that? A "," is an acceptable character to be in a filename. If the files were in an array, you could get away with something like `program -file $(printf '%s,' "${array[@]}")`

Comment: i see! like this? `fileArray=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P,' "${array[@]}")`. It outputs the same way as piping it to sed. But very cool. I should look into array usage. Not used to it.

Comment: Close, an additional () is needed for an array assignment. It would be for like: fileArray=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f))

Comment: `fileArray=($(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P,' | sed -e 
's/,$/\n/'))` Using the sed command to remove the last comma.

Comment: Now that I think more about it, why would it be beneficial to assign it into an array when only calling ${fileArray[0]} is the only assignment that has values? Isn't the whole idea of an array to be able to call each instance by a number assignment? Or am I wrong?

Comment: The idea is hold common data in a single variable. In bash, its has an additional usefulness of properly holding elements that contain spaces, tabs, and newlines. Being able to access individual elements without iterating over the entire array, or expanding it is also useful, but is by no means the only benefit to using an array.

Comment: I see. So the fact that I want to create a variable that has a comma delimited list and that can possibly contain spaces is reason enough to assign it into an array, as an array can handle such instances better than a variable.  Thanks for all the information jordanm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think easier:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%P,' | sed -e 's/,$/\n/'
```

The `sed` expression replaces the terminal `,` by a linebreak.

Comment: what is the `%P` called and is there a reference list of all these types of 'variables'?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the one-liners shown in the other answers, but in order to fill in your script, you could do:

```
if [[ -n $(ls | grep lpt) ]]; then
  for file in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f); do
    #parse output into variable fileList
    fileList="$file,$fileList"
  done
fi

#now remove the trailing comma from the fileList
fileList=$(sed 's/,$//' <<< "$fileList")
```

(Note: your for-loop won't work correctly if your filenames have spaces in them)

Comment: all non-spacing files =D. thanks for adapting it to what I have.

Comment: and thanks for showing me this. I've accomplished this in a batch-file before, but it was funky because it needed delayed expansions and calling the variable as expanded. So much simpler in shell scripting =D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of your loop, you could use `find`'s `-exec` option, along with shell expansion:

```
fileList=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec echo -n "{}," \; | sed 's/,$//')
```

The `sed` bit is just to remove the trailing comma. `sed` is used to edit input streams, i.e. here, it gets piped text from `find` and is editing what it's getting. Since the command given leaves an extra `,` at the end, `sed` uses its substitution command (`s`) to get rid of it. The form is:

```
s/EXPRESSION/REPLACEMENT/
```

So `,$` means "a comma at the end of the line, since `$` means "at the end of the line", and the nothingness between the second and third slashes means it gets replaced by nothing.

As far as the `\;` in `find`, that's just a requirement for using `-exec`, so it knows when it's done reading commands, and it's in the man page. :)

Comment: can you translate `sed 's/,$//` I know you said its to remove the trailing comma, but what is it, for lack of a better word, saying? and why escape the `;`? I'm not "Questioning" you, I'm just curious as I'm new to shell scripting and I want to know the behavior.

Comment: The output I'm getting is incorrect. It shows `./file1,./file2./file3` etc.

Comment: @Mechaflash are you saying you see `./` or no commas after the first one, as in your example? The `./` notation is *correct*, though it may not be what you want. `./` means "in this directory". Anyway, there's a reason I upvoted thiton; his answer is cleaner. ;)

Comment: i missed entering the comma =D. commas are there, just it keeps inserting ./ with each file (which I understand it to be current directory).